# How to execute code from Node.js server command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm just starting with Node.js but I have experience with client-side JavaScript and PHP/Apache.

In your browser you can execute JS code from the developer console at any time. You can manipulate global vars and call global functions and methods. If I call `console.log('Hello world!')` from the browser's developer console, it will log the message to the console I'm using, just like in a script you write.

In Node.js when you call `console.log('Hello world!')` from within your "app", the result is logged as you'd expect, just like JS on the client-side. Can I do what I would do on the client-side?

My question is **can I execute my own JS code from the command line** like I would on the client-side, manipulating vars (such as the HTTP server, filesystem, etc.) and calling functions that are available in my app? I don't care why, I just want to know if I can do it.

Comment: @Juhana It's hardly a duplicate. I don't want to debug my apps nor do I want to use a browser. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: The duplicate tells how to do all the stuff you ask for. Read all the answers, not just the top voted one.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

> V8 comes with an extensive debugger which is accessible out-of-process
> via a simple TCP protocol. Node has a built-in client for this
> debugger. To use this, start Node with the **debug** argument; a prompt
> will appear:
>
> Node's debugger client doesn't support the full range of commands, but
> simple step and inspection is possible. By putting the statement
> **debugger;** into the source code of your script, you will enable a
> breakpoint.
>
> http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

Yes this is possible. You just need to write the statement `debugger` wherever you want your code to stop and you want to use the command line (and start node with the debug argument, eg:   `node debug app.js`

Comment: Looks like what I want. Will try it out, cheers!